Crypto.getRandomValues() not supported from Google Places API
I am geting the this error when I run my expo app
crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported

the app starts and later crashes with this but everything seemed to be working fine earlier. I have deleted node modules and re installed but error persists. after carefully examining the code I discovered the error is coming from react-native-google-places-autocomplete from a file inside a uuid folder from node_modules. I tried commenting out where the error is coming from manually but places api didn't function properly without it.
